# angular browserify including routes file

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I am experimenting with browserify and angular. I have a little issue when trying to include the routes in a separate file. So originally:

```
var login = angular.module('login.module', []);

login.controller('LoginCtrl', require('./login.controller'));
login.service('loginService', require('./login.service'));

login.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/modules/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'login'
        });
});
```

Then I do the following to separate the routes in their own file:

```
login.config('loginRoutes', require('./login.routes'));
```

And in the login.routes.js file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/modules/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'login'
        });
};
```

Sadly, I got the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module login.module due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
```

I am missing something little here, but so far I couldn't find it on my own. Some help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did u mention in the html <html data-ng-app="login.module"

Comment: sure, the login module worked before I tried to separate the routes in a separate file.